# Is it necessary to set the path variable in java installation?

Tags: java, windows, installation-path

[In this link](https://java.com/en/download/help/path.xml), I read:

> Making changes to the system PATH variable is typically not necessary
>   for computers running Windows

What does "typically" mean?

When is it necessary to insert the java directory in the path and when is it not ?

In my company in some PCs the java command is recognized even if the java directory is not present in the path variable, in some others is not, with no evident difference between the two groups of PCs.

Comment: I haven't done it this century.

Comment: Different versions of Java installs differently, so there is no single answer. It also depends on how you install it. Note that only the JRE adds itself to the path. The JDK doesn't.

Comment: If you have ever installed Java 6 or 7 on a particular machine, that leaves behind a copy of "java.exe" in the system folder, which means Java does not need to be on the path in order to use it from the command line.  If you have only ever installed Java 8, then Java needs to be on the path in order to use it from the command line.  (Most people don't use the command line anyway, so the path setting is irrelevant.  I imagine that's what the sentence you've quoted was supposed to mean.)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the PATH when you are using a jdk from the command line (ex. compileing, making jar)

When you make a java script, you want to compile your code, you want to use PATH to reference the java bin folder in the JDK. (Your path varable might look like this: `set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_72\bin`)

Answer:

If you are not making java programs and using the command line to compile/run/debug them, you do not need to set PATH variable.

Hope this helps! ☺